# how to pass parameters in server.js using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to pass parameters data from mongoDB to server side.
And I create global variable diagramData to pass from diagramModel.find() query to app.post function. But it was empty array when console.log(diagramData).Can somebody help me figure it out? Thanks

```
var diagramData = [];
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    diagramModel.find({}, function(err, data) {
      diagramData = data;
    });
});

app.post('/display_bpmnFile', function(req, res) {
    console.log(diagramData);
    res.send({
        file: diagramData
    });
});
```

Comment: are you getting the data value?

Comment: This is not about node and mongo. You need to check how async functions work.

[Understanding Async Programming in node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)

Comment: You will get any value in any time

Comment: data value is in json format;
data = {
      "owner" : "sh529u",
      "text" : "sco_poc.bpmn",
      "users":["wp6307","kz323j","ew6980"],
      "groups":[],
      "string" : "test"
}

Answer (score 0):

> You will not get value in that since when you call your route then it works as `async nature` so most of the chance your array will be empty.

---

> It's not a proper answer since I am writing your connection in route.

Write your connection in somewhere and use it everywhere

```
app.post('/display_bpmnFile', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {//connection code must not be here put it in somewhere else and make it common
    diagramModel.find({}, function(err, data) {
      if (!err) {
        res.send({
          file: data
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```